# json values not supported by jooq

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I am trying to insert into books table using jooq in java. books table has two columns book_id integer,jsonb_column jsonb. However the final query formed is not correct. The values for jsonb is not populated. This is my query formed.

```
insert into book (book_id, jsoncolumn) values (902, );
```

Below is my java code.

```
    Field[] columnNames= new Field[2];
    columnNames[0]=field("book_id");
    columnNames[1]= field("jsoncolumn");
    
    Field[] columnValues= new Field[2];
    columnValues[0]=field("902");
    columnValues[1]=field("{}");
    Query query= create.insertInto(table("book"), 
            columnNames)
            .values(columnValues);
    
    String sql = query.getSQL();
    System.out.println(sql);
```

How to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

If you were using the code generator (which I *highly* recommend!), then most of jOOQ works out of the box. Your query would simply read:

```java
ctx.insertInto(BOOK, BOOK.BOOK_ID, BOOK.JSONCOLUMN)
   .values(902, JSONB.jsonb("{}"))
   .execute();
```

If for some reason you cannot use the code generator, then you have to do what the code generator does for you, manually. Here are the mistakes you made:

1. You didn't specify data types for your field expressions
2. You used [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to define the values of your columns, not [bind values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/)

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```java
Table<?> book = table(name("book"));
Field<Long> bookId = field(name("book_id"), SQLDataType.BIGINT);
Field<JSONB> jsoncolumn = field(name("jsoncolumn"), SQLDataType.JSONB);

ctx.insertInto(book, bookId, jsoncolumn)
   .values(902L, JSONB.jsonb("{}"))
   .execute();
```

Comment: what exactly is BOO,BOOK.BOOK_ID... is it a string? also this is giving me compilation error JSONB.jsonb

Comment: also the fixed version of the code also gives compilation error for me in JSONB.jsonb. this is what i am trying to do 
org.jooq.JSONB.jsonb("{}")

Comment: @Abhishek: *"what exactly is BOO,BOOK.BOOK_ID"* - Well, I recommended using the code generator, so that's generated code. [See here for examples](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-builder-with-code-generation/). Seriously. Use the code generator if you can (i.e. if your schema isn't dynamic). You'll have a *much better* jOOQ experience, not just a good one. :) "*also this is giving me compilation error JSONB.jsonb*" - I'm assuming you're using the latest version of jOOQ. Otherwise, use `JSONB.valueOf()`, which does the same.